# Quickbooks PHP SDK Bill::create() silently failing?

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm calling the Bill and/or VendorCredit facade like so:

```
Bill::create([
[
      'DocNumber' => '12345678',
      'TxnDate' => 2023-12-06,
      'Line' => [
        'DetailType' => 'AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail',
        'Amount' => 23.12,
        'AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail' => [
          'AccountRef' => [
            'value' => 150
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'VendorRef' => [
        'value' => 175
      ]
    ]
])
```

However, nothing gets returned. I added some logging to the bill class, and I can see the data that's passed in is correct, but it never gets to the second log statement. It seems to be  silently failing somewhere and I can't figure out where.

Seems to be something in the `FacadeHelper::reflectArrayToObject` method.

```
 Log::debug($data);
        $BillObject = FacadeHelper::reflectArrayToObject("Bill", $data, $throwException);
        Log::debug($BillObject); <-- never gets here
```

Has anyone else run into this? Oddly, I've used nearly this same code in a similar project and it works flawlessly. I just can't understand what's going on. I've got this in my QuickbooksService class:

`$this->dataService->throwExceptionOnError(true);`

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the line before the log with a try/catch block to see if anything useful comes out of the exception message.

Comment: @PaulT. Unfortunately that's not telling me anything. It seems to be something within the method itself. I was looking for any try/catch blocks in that class that could be suppressing an error, but there's only one so that's not it. It's a recursive method too which makes it a little more difficult to get my mind around.